# How to solve “access denied” error trying to create a message queue?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, .net-5

Only happens when the code is called from .NET. When the same code is compiled as a C++ console app, or called from a C++ console app, it runs without errors.

The following code compiles a C++ DLL called from .NET, and it prints “mq_open failed, code 1, message Operation not permitted”:

```
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))
int mq_test()
{
    const char* name = "/985a8e18-08ee-46e5-acf5-fc4f2ffb4d4f";
    constexpr int oflag = O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC | O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
    constexpr mode_t mode = 0660;

    mq_attr qa;
    memset( &qa, 0, sizeof( qa ) );
    qa.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    qa.mq_msgsize = sizeof( void* );

    int fd = mq_open( name, oflag, mode, &qa );
    if( fd >= 0 )
    {
        mq_unlink( name );
        printf( "mq_open completed OK\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        const int code = errno;
        printf( "mq_open failed, code %i, message %s\n", code, strerror( code ) );
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However, when the same DLL is called from C++ console application, it runs fine and prints ”mq_open completed OK”:

```
// gcc load.cpp -ldl && ./a.out
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using pfnTest = int( * )( );
int main()
{
    void * const handle = dlopen( "./libNativeHelpers.so", RTLD_NOW );
    if( nullptr == handle )
    {
        printf( "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror() );
        return 1;
    }

    const pfnTest pfn = (pfnTest)dlsym( handle, "mq_test" );
    if( nullptr == pfn )
    {
        printf( "dlsym failed: %s\n", dlerror() );
        return 2;
    }
    return pfn();
}
```

I’m running both programs under the same user account, yet the C++ one has all the required permissions, while the C# program doesn’t. Any ideas how to find out what's going on?

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, the architecture is AMD64, the .NET is 5.0.9.

Comment: Regarding your tags: the problem is basically "environment" - not "C++", not "Linux". Q: Is the OS really "ubuntu 20.04.3. LTS" (a standalone install) ... or is it Ubuntu under [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)?  Q: What exactly is your MQ implementation?  OOTB [Posix message queues](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/mq_overview.7.html), or "something else" (e.g. Rabbit MQ)?

Comment: @paulsm4 “not "C++", not "Linux"” How was I supposed to know that before I found the answer? “Is the OS really” yes indeed, despite the hardware’s fake, I’m using VMWare Workstation 16.1.2 to run that Ubuntu. Not sure I understand the last question, that thing is a Linux kernel API: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [snap](https://snapcraft.io/). Microsoft made an interesting choice to ship their .NET framework, designed to be used by software developers, inside a sandbox which is hiding the actual operating system behind an abstraction.

Under the hood, that thing is using [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) kernel module. That’s what produced that access denied status. Again, interesting choice, IMO [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is generally better for such things.

As soon as I uninstalled the snap package of the .NET runtine, and installed the native version with apt-get, my code started to work fine.